# Workaround iPhone's browser not honoring the <label> element

Tags: iphone

Just ran into this recently and I thought it'd be helpful to share.

The HTML `<label>` element is supported in a weird way by iPhone's (v3) browser. Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkTest" /><label for="chkTest">Click me!</label>
```

Tapping the "Click me!" label has no effect, the checkbox is not checked.

Lack of support in a touch device for `<label>` elements puzzled me and I tried to overcome this issue by using javascript. The surprise came when a I noticed a void javascript like the one below also did the trick:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkTest" /><label for="chkTest" onclick="javascript:void(0);">Click me!</label>
```

HTH

Further info:

1. Also works with an empty handler: `onclick=""`
2. Disabling JavaScript inactivates again the label, even if using the empty handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation it looks like assigning the following CSS rule to is enough to trigger the expected label behaviour on the iPhone:

label {cursor: pointer}

Comment: This no longer seems to be working (at least not on iOS 5.1), although the `onclick=""` empty handler trick does still work.