# Check box Label click in iPad

Tags: css, ipad

I have used some check boxes with Lable tag a reason behind it is if user click on text that appropriate check box select, but when I test this in iPad its work fine if user click on direct check box but when click on text its dose not response like its does in desktop

Please check this **[link](http://jsfiddle.net/HqMuN/)**

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue, there's a simple CSS fix which I've wrote about on my blog here: http://www.tjcafferkey.me/problems-clicking-input-label-select-ios-safari/

The CSS is simple:

```css
label > * {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply using an ID/FOR combination?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" />

<label for="mycheckbox">Click here</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Learning from these two questions ([3035954](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035954/workaround-iphones-browser-not-honoring-the-label-element), [7358781](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358781/tapping-on-label-in-mobile-safari)), there seems to be a hack that will produce the behaviour you want:

Adding an empty onclick handler to each label should work, e.g.:

```
<label onclick=""><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</label>
```

Or, alternatively, you could do this via some less intrusive javascript, e.g.:

```
$('label').click(function(){});
```